# Mobile-Chrome-App not able to scroll

Tags: google-chrome-app

I also have this issue. I am using Ubuntu and just completed the Hello world tutorial. I wrote some more text and I am unable to scroll. I can see where the words keep going but nothing I have tried lets it scroll. I have not made any HTML/CSS edits. I have only added more text to the `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some default CSS applied for chrome packaged apps. Putting the following in your CSS should re-enable scrolling:

```
html {
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Someone is putting together a cool guide which might have some more tips. See https://gist.github.com/maicki/7622137#scrolling

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to get it to work by applying the css to body instead of html

Answer (score 0):

Chrome apps have a [default stylesheet](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/renderer/resources/extensions/platform_app.css) applied to them, to help the web "page" be more of an "app" by default.

For Chrome Apps on Mobile, we also include this (well, a nearly identical) default stylesheet.

So that is the reason for that behavior.  Scrolling is absolutely useful in very many contexts, and is absolutely supported in any DOM element by adding `overflow-y: auto;`.

It was simply deemed to be the wrong default for packaged apps which live inside a dedicated window of set bounds and where we encourage not having full page content overflow (very much the opposite of the web).  Most apps usually surround a main scrolling element with fixed navigational elements (but not always).

FYI, there is also another [open issue](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/issues/8) for Chrome Apps on Mobile to replicate yet more of the Chrome for Desktop default styles.