# Chrome App cannot be scroll

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have created few linked web pages that can be navigated via index.html page. Index.html page's content is somewhat lengthy and so I have to scroll that page. It works fine as a web page. Then I converted it into chrome app. When I launch the app, the scroll bar is not shown there. I cannot see the below content. How can can I get this resolved. (Using as an app was my target, so I cannot use it as a web page.)

Comment: Example https://github.com/sowbug/happynine/blob/master/chrome_app/styles.css#L36

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
html, body {
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21710397/29701

Basically it's due to the default style sheet. Chrome packaged apps are most often intended to not scroll the main body content. You can override this should you chose to (with css), but consider if you should.

Comment: Just a bit of flame: normal desktop apps have a scroll when their window can't show its content without scrollbars. So I still can't get why chrome developers came to such a strange solution - make hidden scrollbars.

Comment: Chrome Apps are written in HTML but are not web sites.  We would prefer you write apps which look like apps. You are free to create scrolling elements, but scrolling the body was just not a good default.